# PyQt QPushButton signal handling

Tags: python, pyqt4, signals-slots, qpushbutton

I have a `repeat` python function and a *test.ui* which has only one push-button. My doubt is how to loop the same function exactly once for every time the button is clicked. Because for me whenever I perform:

```
self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.repeat)
```

it loops many times into the function instead of a single time. I found this by incrementing a value for every time we reach the function. How to reach the function `repeat` exactly once for every click on the push-button?

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "test.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)


class Login(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    i=1
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.setText("iam in init")
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.repeat)
    def repeat(self):

        self.pushButton.setText("iam in repeat"+str(self.i))

        self.i=self.i+1

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.repeat)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    app=QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Login()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: It sounds like you may have connected the signal multiple times. Show the complete code where you are making the connection.

Comment: I have included my code below

Answer (score 2):

Loooking at your code, you have established the connection multiple times. You should establish it with `self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.repeat)` only in your `__init__` but not in `repeat()` function. In other words, delete the second occurrence (i.e. in `repeat()`) and you should be fine. The connection should be established only once because once established it lasts till `disconnect()` is called on it or till the `slot` or the `signal` are destroyed.